# How do I write 870037764750?

Tags: mathematics

If 2 is `b`, 12 is `cb'b,` and 286992882 is `f'cb,c'b'b,,b` then how would I write 870037764750?

Comment: for math class? http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/express-number-870037764750-using-notation-problem-study-55-introduction-history-math-book-q15219527

Comment: @oMiKeY, if so, I want to downvote it. Very bad form posting homework questions on Puzzling.SE

Comment: Hahaha! Oh man, that's a really funny coincidence to me. No I have never seen this question before, and I simply constructed the number on the question to be an interesting one to construct. I guess whoever wrote that maths question had a similar idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would write 870037764750 as

> `f'd,e'b'b,,d'c,c'b,b`

The rule behind this is

> based on the prime factorization. The letters represent the prime numbers (`b`=2, `c`=3, `d`=5, ...), while `'` stands for **^(** and `,` stands for **)**.
>  `b` $= 2$
>  `cb'b,` $= 3 \times 2^{2} = 12$
>  `f'cb,c'b'b,,b` $= 11^{3 \times 2} \times 3^{2^{2}} \times 2 = 286992882$
>  `f'd,e'b'b,,d'c,c'b,b` $= 11^{5} \times 7^{2^{2}} \times 5^{3} \times 3^{2} \times 2 = 870037764750$

Comment: Good work, that is exactly right. I came up with this as an entirely alien form of writing numbers (compared to our common positional number systems), and then thought people here might be interested in puzzling out the answer.

Comment: Your new system has the disadvantage of what happens after z? Other then that, its pretty fun.

Comment: @Cheiron, try adding two of those numbers in that notation ;)

Comment: @Geliormth On the other hand, multiplication and exponentiation are a cinch! ;)

Comment: @Geliormth 12+286992882 is only three characters in this notation! I have no idea which character the first one would be, but only needing 3 characters is clearly superior!

Comment: @Cheiron That is certainly an issue, I did use all lower and uppercase English alphabet, the Greek alphabet and some of the Cyrillic alphabet, and you would run into a problem for lacking a symbol for a prime at around 400 some. Obviously not very useful, except possibly for multiplication as Mendes points out.